# Неправильно работает нейронка

Tags: python

Читал книгу "Основы искусственного интеллекта в примерах на python". В ней есть таблица, в которой показано после какого количества циклов простейшая нейронка должна начать узнавать цифру. Я просто скопировал оттуда код, но он не выдает даже близко значений из книги. Пока маленькое количество циклов , нейронка еще может узнавать только нужное число, если уходить за тысячу, то она или не узнает ничего вообще, или выдает слишком слишком много совпадений

```
import random
nшnO= list('111101101101111')
nшnl= list('001001001001001')
nшn2= list('111001111100111')
nшnЗ= list('111001111001111')
nшn4= list('101101111001001')
nшn5= list('111100111001111')
nшnб= list('111100111101111')
nшn7= list('111001001001001')
nшn8= list('111101111101111')
nшn9= list('111101111001111')

nums= [nшnO, nшnl, nшn2, nшnЗ, nшn4, nшn5, nшnб, nшn7, nшn8, nшn9]
tema = 5
n_sensor = 15
weights = [0 for i in range(n_sensor)]

def perceptron(Sensor):
    b = 7
    s = 0
    for i in range(n_sensor):
        s += int(Sensor[i]) * weights[i]
        if s >= b:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def decrease(numЬer):
    for i in range(n_sensor):
        if int(numЬer[i])== 1:
            weights[i] -= 1
def increase(numЬer):
    for i in range(n_sensor):
        if int(numЬer[i]) == 1:

            weights[i] += 1
n =10000
for i in range(n):
    j=random.randint(0,9)
    r = perceptron(nums[j])
    if j != tema:
        if r:
            decrease(nums[j])
    else:
        if not r:
            increase(nums[tema])
print(weights)
print("O это 5?", perceptron(nшnO))
print("l это 5?", perceptron(nшnl))
print("2 это 5?", perceptron(nшn2))
print("З это 5? ", perceptron(nшnЗ))
print("4 это 5?", perceptron(nшn4))
print("5 это 5?" ,perceptron(nшn5))
print("б это 5?", perceptron(nшnб))
print("7 это 5?", perceptron(nшn7))
print("B это 5?", perceptron(nшn8))
print("9 это 5? ", perceptron(nшn9))
```

Comment: [дубль?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1528799/479903)